# Как устроены указатели на уровне ассемблера?

Tags: c++, ассемблер, указатели

```
void foo(int a)
{
 a = a + a;
}

void foo(int *a)
{
 *a = *a + *a;
}
```

**ASM:**

```
foo(int):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi
        sal     DWORD PTR [rbp-4]
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
foo(int*):
        push    rbp
        mov     rbp, rsp
        mov     QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     eax, DWORD PTR [rax]
        lea     edx, [rax+rax]
        mov     rax, QWORD PTR [rbp-8]
        mov     DWORD PTR [rax], edx
        nop
        pop     rbp
        ret
```

Как устроены указатели на уровне ассемблера ?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развёрнутые вопросы. Для получения ответа поясните, в чём именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д. Приведите пример, наглядно демонстрирующий проблему.

Comment: *Как устроены указатели на уровне ассемблера ?* Да никак. Горсть (сколько именно - зависит от режима и какой именно указатель) байтов в памяти или регистре. От не-указателя и не отличишь, ежели не знать...

Comment: Указатель содержит адрес в памяти. Код, работающий с указателями, "на уровне ассемблера" представляет собой код, работающий с адресами.

Comment: `Как устроены указатели` — просто беззнаковые числа размером с машинное слово. Пример применения: `mov DWORD PTR [rbp-4], edi` означает «возьми значение регистра rbp, вычти из него 4, *и в четырёхбайтовую ячейку памяти по получившемуся адресу* помести значение регистра edi». Вот в том, что выделено курсивом, и заключается единственное отличие указателей от прочих простых типов данных.

Comment: `mov QWORD PTR [rbp-8], rdi` в локальную переменную в стеке положили "указатель", т.е. адрес в памяти, на который указывает `a`. после этого перенесли его в eax (правда переносить через память не имело смысла, но компилятор так устроен). И дальше уже обращаемся к данным по этому адресу (`mov eax, DWORD PTR [rax]` (в eax помещаем двойное слово, находящееся по адресу в rax))

Comment: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/qSC93h - тот же код, скомпилированный со включенной оптимизацией

Answer (score 7, accepted):

У процессора, т.е. в языке ассемблера, фактически все операции в оперативной памяти происходят "по указателю". Обратиться к ячейке памяти (переменной) можно только по ее конкретному адресу. Адрес при этом должен быть доступен инструкции непосредственно, т.е. находиться в самой инструкции, в регистре или вычисляться из регистров и констант. Указатель в языке *C* это переменная в памяти, содержащая тот самый адрес, по которому надо обращаться к данным.

В приведенных вами примерах параметр функции передается через регистр. В первом случае передано само 32 битное значение, поэтому оно в регистре edi. Во втором - это 64 битный адрес, т.е. указатель (он в 64 битном регистре rdi).
В этих примерах так же много лишнего кода (видимо выключена оптимизация). В первом примере значение из регистра переноситься в локальную область стека (в переменную a) и она умножается на 2. Достаточно было бы `sal edi`. Хотя конечно одного ret было бы более чем достаточно, потому что код фактически ничего не делает, он меняет свою локальную переменную, которую никуда не возвращает.
Второй пример в идеале можно сократить до:

```
foo(int*):  ; В rdi указатель на 32 битную переменную.
  mov eax, DWORD PTR [rdi] ; Помещаем в eax значение, находящееся по адресу (указателю) rdi
  sal eax                  ; сдвиг eax влево на 1 бит ( eax*=2 )
  mov DWORD PTR [rdi], eax ; Помещаем eax обратно по адресу из rdi
  ret
```

Обратите внимание, что работа с локальными переменными, находящимися в стеке шла точно так же, в rbp находится указатель на текущий кадр стека, доступ к переменным осуществляется по этому адресу с некоторым смещением (`[rbp+8]`). Фактически rbp это точно такой же указатель, по которому происходит работа. Но язык высокого уровня, для удобства программиста отличает просто переменные и указатели

Comment: "Адрес при этом должен находиться в регистре." - это не обязательно верно. Есть платформы с таким требованием. Но многие платформы поддерживают процессорные инструкции с встроенными прямо в инструкцию адресами. Многие платформы поддерживают процессорные инструкции с вычисляемыми "на лету" адресами (например, как сумма регистра и константы). Поэтому явное предварительно формирование целевого адреса в регистре - не обязательно.

Comment: @AnT И у меня даже почти в самом конце приведен пример со смещением относительно базового указателя. Вопрос же был не в режимах адресации. А адрес внутри инструкции по сути тот же указатель. Но ради точности изложения предложение поправил, хотя теперь оно мне меньше нравиться